# WCF recursive collection data contract not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I had a working solution in 2010, I have moved to 2012 and it was working just fine as long as I didn't modify my reference to WCF service in Silverlight project.

Now I am getting following error on class that was previously working just fine. I tried rollbacking code to a working version, and just updating service reference in SL project,  and hitting build.

It builds before, but doesn't after. Note that everything is working too, and that collection is sent between server and client just fine.

Full error text is here:

> ```
> Warning   134 Custom tool warning: Cannot import wsdl:portType
> Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension:
> ```
>
> System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
>       Error: Type 'MyAssembly.ResultTreeDto' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the
>   definition of collection 'MyAssembly.ResultTreeDto' to remove
>   references to itself.

Any help greatly appreciated. Just in case: class can be considered recursive, here is a sample code from it:

```
 public class ResultTreeDto 
    {

        public List<ResultTreeDto> Leafs { get; set; }
        .....
```

I am honestly shocked. Hitting this update service reference button causes so much trouble too often.

I am not sure if issue is related to SL only, from error it sounds like not only to it I think.

What could have gone wrong since my last update service reference call, I am really not sure where to start to look.

Comment: To my understanding a more recent patch fixed a similar issue. Can you try installing http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750149 (windows 8) or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750147 (other OSes) to see if that solves your issue.

Comment: OMG you are the most amazing person ever. Please add this as answer and ill +1 and mark as answer, helped and solved problem. huge thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding a more recent patch fixed a similar issue. Can you try installing http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750149 (windows 8) or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750147 (other OSes) to see if that solves your issue.

Comment: thanks. How did you come up with idea that this is related I wonder? What rang a bell for you?